# Java Concurrent and Parallel GC

Tags: java, garbage-collection, concurrency

This article [here](http://www.petefreitag.com/articles/gctuning/) suggests to use `-XX:+UseParNewGC` "To enable a parallel young generation GC with the concurrent GC".

My confusion is that in order to enable both parallel and concurrent GC, should I

- use `-XX:+UseParNewGC` or
- use both `-XX:+UseParNewGC` *and* `-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC` ?

#### PS

I am using JVM 6.

Comment: Which JVM version are you using? There are some differences between 1.4.2 and 5 or 6.

Comment: Some confusion might arise from the expression "young generation", which in this context has to do with the age of the Java objects in your heap (not how modern the GC is).

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Since the document you linked was for a 1.4.2 VM that's what I'll assume you're using (JVMs 5 and 6 behave differently).

From [http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/](https://web.archive.org/web/20120624153924/http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/)

> if -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC is used on
>   the command line then the flag
>   UseParNewGC is also set to true if it
>   is not otherwise explicitly set on the
>   command line

So the answer is you only need to use -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC and it will enable the concurrent collector with the parallel young generation collector.

Edit: for Java 6, the same flag (-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC) enables the concurrent collector. The choice of collector you want depends on a few things, and you should test different configurations. But there are some very general guidelines. If you have a single processor, single thread machine then you should use the serial collector (default for some configurations, can be enabled explicitly for with -XX:+UseSerialGC). For multiprocessor machines where your workload is basically CPU bound, use the parallel collector. This is enabled by default if you use the -server flag, or you can enable it explicitly with -XX:+UseParallelGC. If you'd rather keep the GC pauses shorter at the expense of using more total CPU time for GC, and you have more than one CPU, you can use the concurrent collector (-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC). Note that the concurrent collector tends to require more RAM allocated to the JVM than the serial or parallel collectors for a given workload because some memory fragmentation can occur.

Comment: i still dont get it, so To enable a parallel young generation GC with the concurrent GC do i have to use both concmarksweepgc and parnewgc or just concmarksweepgc would do?

Comment: Just -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC and I think the UseParNewGC flag has no effect (or might even cause an error) in Java 6.

Comment: You can check with java -XX:+PrintCommandLineFlags -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -version  =>  -XX:+UseParNewGC is automatically set. (Tested with 1.6.0_26).

Answer (score 7):

This blog entry has a nice breakdown of the different collectors, and which options are valid: http://blogs.oracle.com/jonthecollector/entry/our_collectors

Answer (score 7):

java/JDK 6 GC tuning : http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/gc-tuning-6-140523.html. This is from SUN (now Oracle). The full stuff.

Also, see 
 http://kirk.blog-city.com/is_your_concurrent_collector_failing_you.htm
http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/

Answer (score 5):

Java GC tuning is basically a dark art, but in my application (runs with a 50+GB heap, and 16 physical cores) the ConcMarkSweep collector resulted in a 3x speedup over the -server default, and a 2.2x speedup over ParallelOldGC.

If you aren't sharing the machine with other processes (so idle cores are just wasted) use the ConcMarkSweepGC.

Comment: Can you explain a bit more about this "If you aren't sharing the machine with other processes (so idle cores are just wasted) use the ConcMarkSweepGC." ?

Answer (score 2):

ParNew is the default young generation collector when CMS is used.You just have to specify -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC to use CMS and ParNew will be used by default. CMS is a good collector if avoiding GC jitters is of higher priority but if throughput is more important for eg for a batch like job the default SUN parallel collector does a better job.

Answer (score 0):

You cannot enable two GC options at the same time. I would suggest you to use CMS which is better than and next generation GC compare to UseParNewGC. and if you use Java 1.7 or later and heap size is relatively bigger (like > 4GB) consider using G1.