# Difference between -XX:+UseParallelGC and -XX:+UseParNewGC

Tags: java, jvm-arguments

They are algorithms for the young generation garbage collection.

The second one (UseParNewGC) gets activated automatically with the concurrent tenured generation garbage collection (see [Java Concurrent and Parallel GC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/220388/java-concurrent-and-parallel-gc)) but, is there a difference between the two parallel algorithms?

Answer (score 128, accepted):

After a lot of searching, the best explanation I've found is from Java Performance Tuning website in [Question of the month: 1.4.1 Garbage collection algorithms, January 29th, 2003](http://www.javaperformancetuning.com/news/qotm026.shtml)

> **Young generation garbage collection algorithms**
>
> The *(original) copying collector* (Enabled by default). When this collector kicks in, all application threads are stopped, and the copying collection proceeds using one thread (which means only one CPU even if on a multi-CPU machine). This is known as a stop-the-world collection, because basically the JVM pauses everything else until the collection is completed.
>
> The *parallel copying collector* (Enabled using -XX:+UseParNewGC). Like the original copying collector, this is a stop-the-world collector. However this collector parallelizes the copying collection over multiple threads, which is more efficient than the original single-thread copying collector for multi-CPU machines (though not for single-CPU machines). This algorithm potentially speeds up young generation collection by a factor equal to the number of CPUs available, when compared to the original singly-threaded copying collector.
>
> The *parallel scavenge collector* (Enabled using -XX:UseParallelGC). This is like the previous parallel copying collector, but the algorithm is tuned for gigabyte heaps (over 10GB) on multi-CPU machines. This collection algorithm is designed to maximize throughput while minimizing pauses. It has an optional adaptive tuning policy which will automatically resize heap spaces. If you use this collector, you can only use the the original mark-sweep collector in the old generation (i.e. the newer old generation concurrent collector cannot work with this young generation collector).

From this information, it seems the main difference (apart from CMS cooperation) is that UseParallelGC supports [ergonomics](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.5.0/docs/guide/vm/gc-ergonomics.html)  while UseParNewGC doesn't.

Comment: Slightly more up to date link http://www.fasterj.com/articles/oraclecollectors1.shtml

Comment: @phunehehe Thanks for the link! It's very helpful.

Answer (score 23):

[Parallel GC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javase/tech/vmoptions-jsp-140102.html)

- XX:+UseParallelGC    Use parallel garbage collection for scavenges. (Introduced in 1.4.1)
- XX:+UseParallelOldGC Use parallel garbage collection for the full collections. Enabling this option automatically sets -XX:+UseParallelGC. (Introduced in 5.0 update 6.)

[UseParNewGC](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/gc1-4-2-135950.html#3.2.%20The%20Young%20Generation%7Coutline)

> **UseParNewGC**
>   A parallel version of the young generation copying collector is used
>   with the concurrent collector (i.e. if -XX:+ UseConcMarkSweepGC is
>   used on the command line then the flag UseParNewGC is also set to true
>   if it is not otherwise explicitly set on the command line).

Perhaps the easiest way to understand was combinations of garbage collection algorithms made by [Alexey Ragozin](http://blog.ragozin.info/2011/09/hotspot-jvm-garbage-collection-options.html)

```html
<table border="1" style="width:100%">
  <tr>
    <td align="center">Young collector</td>
    <td align="center">Old collector</td>
    <td align="center">JVM option</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Serial (DefNew)</td>
    <td>Serial Mark-Sweep-Compact</td>
    <td>-XX:+UseSerialGC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Parallel scavenge (PSYoungGen)</td>
    <td>Serial Mark-Sweep-Compact (PSOldGen)</td>
    <td>-XX:+UseParallelGC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Parallel scavenge (PSYoungGen)</td>
    <td>Parallel Mark-Sweep-Compact (ParOldGen)</td>
    <td>-XX:+UseParallelOldGC</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Serial (DefNew)</td>
    <td>Concurrent Mark Sweep</td>
    <td>
      <p>-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC</p>
      <p>-XX:-UseParNewGC</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Parallel (ParNew)</td>
    <td>Concurrent Mark Sweep</td>
    <td>
      <p>-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC</p>
      <p>-XX:+UseParNewGC</p>
    </td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">G1</td>
    <td>-XX:+UseG1GC</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Conclusion:

1. Apply -XX:+UseParallelGC when you require parallel collection method over *YOUNG* generation **ONLY**, (**but** still) use serial-mark-sweep method as *OLD* generation collection
2. Apply -XX:+UseParallelOldGC when you require parallel collection method over *YOUNG* generation (automatically sets -XX:+UseParallelGC) **AND** *OLD* generation collection
3. Apply -XX:+UseParNewGC & -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC when you require parallel collection method over *YOUNG* generation **AND** require CMS method as your collection over *OLD* generation memory
4. You can't apply -XX:+UseParallelGC or -XX:+UseParallelOldGC with -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC simultaneously, that's why your require -XX:+UseParNewGC to be paired with CMS otherwise use -XX:+UseSerialGC explicitly **OR** -XX:**-**UseParNewGC if you wish to use serial method against young generation

Comment: Must be `-XX:-UseParallelGC`.

Comment: Note: Conclusion #1 is not correct anymore. Applying `-XX:+UseParallelGC` leads to use parallel GC for both, young and old GC for modern JVMs. See https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-6679764?focusedCommentId=12410139&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels:comment-tabpanel#comment-12410139

Answer (score 15):

UseParNewGC usually knowns as "parallel young generation collector" is same in all ways as the parallel garbage collector (-XX:+UseParallelGC), except that its more sophiscated and effiecient. Also it can be used with a "concurrent low pause collector".

See [Java GC FAQ](https://web.archive.org/web/20110714032357/http://java.sun.com/docs/hotspot/gc1.4.2/faq.html), question 22 for more information.

Note that there are some known bugs with UseParNewGC

Comment: Do you know which known bugs or which JVM version has them?

Answer (score 3):

Using -XX:+UseParNewGC along with -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC, will cause higher pause time for Minor GCs, when compared to -XX:+UseParallelGC.

This is because, promotion of objects from Young to Old Generation will require running a Best-Fit algorithm (due to old generation fragmentation) to find an address for this object.
Running such an algorithm is not required when using -XX:+UseParallelGC, as +UseParallelGC can be configured only with MarkandCompact Collector, in which case there is no fragmentation.

Comment: This is a really good insight. Did you perform any tests to confirm it?

Answer (score 0):

I will try to answer this question using **[official Oracle docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/technotes/tools/unix/java.html)**:

## What is the purpose of -XX:+UseParNewGC

The purpose of this argument is to enable the use of parallel threads for GC in the young generation.

## -XX:+UseParallelGC v/s -XX:+UseParNewGC

- `-XX:+UseParallelGC` is parallel collector and `-XX:+UseParNewGC` is parallel young generation collector.
- Parallel young generation collector is similar to the parallel garbage collector in intent and differs in implementation. Unlike the parallel collector (­XX:+UseParallelGC) this parallel young generation collector can be used with the concurrent low pause collector that collects the
  tenured generation.

## When -XX:+UseParNewGC should be enabled/used?

> By default this option is disabled and it is automatically
> enabled when you set the -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC option. Using the
> -XX:+UseParNewGC option without the -XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC option was deprecated in JDK 8.

## In Summary

The whole purpose of this argument is to enable the use of parallel threads for GC in the young generation. In Java 8 use of this argument without the use of CMS collector (-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC) is deprecated and with Java 9 this argument itself is deprecated because this argument can only be used with CMS collector and CMS collector itself was deprecated in Java 9.

Answer (score 0):

The CMS collector is designed to eliminate the long pauses associated with the full GC
cycles of the throughput and serial collectors. CMS stops all application threads during
a minor GC, which it also performs with multiple threads. Notably, though, CMS uses
a different algorithm to collect the young generation (`-XX:+UseParNewGC`) than the
throughput collector uses (`-XX:+UseParallelGC`).
Instead of stopping the application threads during a full GC, CMS uses one or more
background threads to periodically scan through the old generation and discard unused
objects. This makes CMS a low-pause collector: application threads are only paused
during minor collections, and for some very short periods of time at certain points as
the background threads scan the old generation. The overall amount of time that application threads are stopped is much less than with the throughput collector.