# Replication timeout exception is occuring often in infinispan replicated cache added in wildfly 10 cluster(2 nodes)

Tags: caching, wildfly-10, infinispan

We are setting up a clustered environment using wildfly 10 of 2 nodes. We have added a new cache-container and replicated cache named 'userSessionData' for sharing data across two servers. Standalone-full-ha.xml is used. Everything is working fine in our development environment.

But in client pre-prod environment, quite often, we are getting replication timeout exception. In our dev environment, we are using default remote-timeout setting i.e. 17500 ms, which I think corresponds to replication timeout. In client pre-prod environment, we have increased it to 60000 ms i.e. 1 min, but still getting same exception quite often. One of the timeout issue scenario:- When user login into application,then we put user session details into cache. During writing into cache, exception occurs.

I have attached infinispan configuration, Java codes used during cache writing and exception.  Also pasted it below.

Below is the infinispan configuration for added cache.

```
<cache-container name="userSessionData_cache" default-cache="default" jndi-name="infinispan/userSessionData_cache">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <replicated-cache name="userSessionData" jndi-name="infinispan/userSessionData_cache/userSessionData" mode="SYNC" remote-timeout="60000">
                    <transaction mode="BATCH"/>
                </replicated-cache>
</cache-container>
```

Below is the Java class code which will call another Java class used for cache:

```
public class UserSessionTracker {

    private UserSessionTracker() {
    }
    private static UserSessionTracker instance = new UserSessionTracker();

    public static void putUserSession(String userName, String sessionId) {
        synchronized (instance) {
                UserSessionDataCacheManager.getInstance().putUserSession(userName, sessionId);
        }
    }
 }
```

Below is the java class used for cache (Singleton pattern for class is used ) :

```
@ManagedBean(name = "userSessionDataCacheManager", eager = true)
@ApplicationScoped
public class UserSessionDataCacheManager {

@Resource(name = "java:jboss/infinispan/userSessionData_cache/userSessionData")
    private Cache<String, java.util.Hashtable<String, Object>> entityCache = null;

    private static UserSessionDataCacheManager configInstance = null;

    public UserSessionDataCacheManager() {
        configInstance = this;
    }

    @PostConstruct
    public void start() {
System.out.println("Cache name: " + entityCache.getName());
    }

    public static UserSessionDataCacheManager getInstance() {
        if (configInstance == null) {
            createInstance();
        }
        return configInstance;
    }

    private static void createInstance() {
        configInstance = new UserSessionDataCacheManager();
    }

    public void putUserSession(String userName, String sessionId) {
System.out.println("inside  putUserSession");
    java.util.Hashtable<String, Object> sessionData = new java.util.Hashtable<String, Object>();
        sessionData.put("Session", sessionId);
        entityCache.put(userName, sessionData);

    }
}
```

Below is the exception log.

```
2017-07-27 11:53:54,539 INFO  [stdout] (default task-15) inside putUserSession

2017-07-27 11:54:54,571 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor] (default task-15) ISPN000136: Error executing command PrepareCommand, writing keys [F2959267]: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Replication timeout for fit-r3stems01
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.checkRsp(JGroupsTransport.java:801)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.lambda$invokeRemotelyAsync$1(JGroupsTransport.java:642)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.RspListFuture.call(RspListFuture.java:47)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.RspListFuture.call(RspListFuture.java:16)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2017-07-27 11:54:54,571 ERROR [org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionCoordinator] (default task-15) ISPN000097: Error while processing a prepare in a single-phase transaction: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Replication timeout for fit-r3stems01
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.checkRsp(JGroupsTransport.java:801)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.lambda$invokeRemotelyAsync$1(JGroupsTransport.java:642)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.RspListFuture.call(RspListFuture.java:47)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.RspListFuture.call(RspListFuture.java:16)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2017-07-27 11:55:54,587 ERROR [org.infinispan.interceptors.InvocationContextInterceptor] (default task-15) ISPN000136: Error executing command RollbackCommand, writing keys [F2959267]: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Replication timeout for fit-r3stems01
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.checkRsp(JGroupsTransport.java:801)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.lambda$invokeRemotelyAsync$1(JGroupsTransport.java:642)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.RspListFuture.call(RspListFuture.java:47)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.RspListFuture.call(RspListFuture.java:16)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2017-07-27 11:55:54,587 WARN  [org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionCoordinator] (default task-15) ISPN000141: Could not rollback prepared 1PC transaction. This transaction will be rolled back by the recovery process, if enabled. Transaction: LocalXaTransaction{xid=DummyXid{id=77}} LocalTransaction{remoteLockedNodes=null, isMarkedForRollback=false, lockedKeys=[], backupKeyLocks=[], topologyId=3, stateTransferFlag=null} org.infinispan.transaction.xa.LocalXaTransaction@8b: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Replication timeout for fit-r3stems01
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.checkRsp(JGroupsTransport.java:801)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.lambda$invokeRemotelyAsync$1(JGroupsTransport.java:642)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.RspListFuture.call(RspListFuture.java:47)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.RspListFuture.call(RspListFuture.java:16)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

2017-07-27 11:55:54,587 WARN  [org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction] (default task-15) ISPN000112: exception while committing: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
    at org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionCoordinator.handleCommitFailure(TransactionCoordinator.java:207)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionCoordinator.commit(TransactionCoordinator.java:159)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.xa.TransactionXaAdapter.commit(TransactionXaAdapter.java:114)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.finishResource(DummyTransaction.java:401)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.commitResources(DummyTransaction.java:448)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.runCommit(DummyTransaction.java:321)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.commit(DummyTransaction.java:108)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.infinispan.InfinispanBatch.close(InfinispanBatch.java:71)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSession.requestDone(DistributableSession.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.updateSessionAccessTime(ServletContextImpl.java:814)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:565)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:202)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Replication timeout for fit-r3stems01
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.checkRsp(JGroupsTransport.java:801)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.lambda$invokeRemotelyAsync$1(JGroupsTransport.java:642)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.RspListFuture.call(RspListFuture.java:47)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.RspListFuture.call(RspListFuture.java:16)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    ... 3 more

2017-07-27 11:55:54,712 WARN  [org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow] (default task-15) javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException: org.infinispan.commons.CacheException: javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException
    at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.infinispan.InfinispanBatch.close(InfinispanBatch.java:74)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.web.undertow.session.DistributableSession.requestDone(DistributableSession.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.ServletContextImpl.updateSessionAccessTime(ServletContextImpl.java:814)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.responseDone(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:565)
    at io.undertow.servlet.spec.HttpServletResponseImpl.sendRedirect(HttpServletResponseImpl.java:202)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ManagedFilter.doFilter(ManagedFilter.java:61)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler$FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.FilterHandler.handleRequest(FilterHandler.java:84)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletSecurityRoleHandler.handleRequest(ServletSecurityRoleHandler.java:62)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletDispatchingHandler.handleRequest(ServletDispatchingHandler.java:36)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.SecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:78)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.SSLInformationAssociationHandler.handleRequest(SSLInformationAssociationHandler.java:131)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.handleRequest(ServletAuthenticationCallHandler.java:57)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractConfidentialityHandler.handleRequest(AbstractConfidentialityHandler.java:46)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.handleRequest(ServletConfidentialityConstraintHandler.java:64)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.handleRequest(AuthenticationMechanismsHandler.java:60)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.security.CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.handleRequest(CachedAuthenticatedSessionHandler.java:77)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.NotificationReceiverHandler.handleRequest(NotificationReceiverHandler.java:50)
    at io.undertow.security.handlers.AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.handleRequest(AbstractSecurityContextAssociationHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at org.wildfly.extension.undertow.security.jacc.JACCContextIdHandler.handleRequest(JACCContextIdHandler.java:61)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.server.handlers.PredicateHandler.handleRequest(PredicateHandler.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.handleFirstRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:292)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$100(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:138)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$2.call(ServletInitialHandler.java:135)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction$1.call(ServletRequestContextThreadSetupAction.java:48)
    at io.undertow.servlet.core.ContextClassLoaderSetupAction$1.call(ContextClassLoaderSetupAction.java:43)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.api.LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper$1.call(LegacyThreadSetupActionWrapper.java:44)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.dispatchRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:272)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler.access$000(ServletInitialHandler.java:81)
    at io.undertow.servlet.handlers.ServletInitialHandler$1.handleRequest(ServletInitialHandler.java:104)
    at io.undertow.server.Connectors.executeRootHandler(Connectors.java:202)
    at io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange$1.run(HttpServerExchange.java:805)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: javax.transaction.HeuristicMixedException
    at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.finishResource(DummyTransaction.java:439)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.commitResources(DummyTransaction.java:448)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.runCommit(DummyTransaction.java:321)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.commit(DummyTransaction.java:108)
    at org.wildfly.clustering.ee.infinispan.InfinispanBatch.close(InfinispanBatch.java:71)
    ... 161 more
Caused by: javax.transaction.xa.XAException
    at org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionCoordinator.handleCommitFailure(TransactionCoordinator.java:207)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.impl.TransactionCoordinator.commit(TransactionCoordinator.java:159)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.xa.TransactionXaAdapter.commit(TransactionXaAdapter.java:114)
    at org.infinispan.transaction.tm.DummyTransaction.finishResource(DummyTransaction.java:401)
    ... 165 more
Caused by: org.infinispan.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Replication timeout for fit-r3stems01
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.checkRsp(JGroupsTransport.java:801)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.JGroupsTransport.lambda$invokeRemotelyAsync$1(JGroupsTransport.java:642)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.uniApply(CompletableFuture.java:602)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$UniApply.tryFire(CompletableFuture.java:577)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.postComplete(CompletableFuture.java:474)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture.complete(CompletableFuture.java:1962)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.RspListFuture.call(RspListFuture.java:47)
    at org.infinispan.remoting.transport.jgroups.RspListFuture.call(RspListFuture.java:16)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$201(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:180)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    ... 3 more
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: Point noted. Thanks. It would not be repeated next time.

Comment: OK, thanks. Regarding your edit, [WildFly](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WildFly) is the correct casing: it is camel-cased.

Comment: The typical thing to do here is figuring out why the replication timeouts are appearing. There are all sorts of possibilities, but you should start by checking memory consumption and whether GC is happening in the other node. You should also see if you can get some thread dumps in the node that is timing out, maybe something hanging?...etc

Answer (score 2):

We had an issue where these timeouts occurred during garbage collection events using the default throughput garbage collection.  Which can be tuned multiple ways to reduce pausing including parallel gc or cms collection.

Remote possibility for some sort of network issue as well depending upon how you are using jgroups, but in my observation this more likely occurs during the "stop the world" garbage collection condition as services grow under memory pressure.

`-XX:+UseConcMarkSweepGC -XX:+UseParNewGC`

Since infinispan is a cache the timeouts are so small that they exceed the jvm pause millis that are normally considered acceptable for some applications.

http://infinispan.org/docs/stable/performance_guide/performance_guide.html#garbage_collection

https://developer.jboss.org/thread/269569?_sscc=t

[Difference between -XX:UseParallelGC and -XX:+UseParNewGC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101518/difference-between-xxuseparallelgc-and-xxuseparnewgc)